# Can't persist results of [ngbTypeahead] to [resultTemplate]

Tags: html, angular, typescript, rxjs, ng-bootstrap

I'm implementing ngbTypeahead in my html with the following code

```
<ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
    <ngb-highlight [result]="r.FirstName" [term]="t"></ngb-highlight>
</ng-template>

<input name="primaryOwner"
       type="text"
       class="form-control pl-2"
       [(ngModel)]="employee"
       [ngbTypeahead]="search"
       [resultTemplate]="rt" />
```

This is the search function

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    return text$.pipe(
        debounceTime(200),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        map(term => {
            if (term.length < 2) {
                return [];
            } else {
                this.myApiCall.employeeSearch(term)
                    .then(response => {
                        if (response.Success) {
                                return response.Employees;
                            });
                        } else {
                            return [];
                        }
                    });
            }
        })
    );
};
```

This is an example of what kind of array I am returning via the map function.

```
[
    {FirstName: "Silvana", LastName: "Joye", IdentificationNumber: "018377", EmailAddress: "Silvana.Joye@company.com"},
    {FirstName: "Diarmuid", LastName: "Jochbed", IdentificationNumber: "692543", EmailAddress: "Diarmuid.Jochbed@company.com"},
    {FirstName: "Jopa", LastName: "Epp", IdentificationNumber: "913960", EmailAddress: "Jopa.Epp@company.com"}
]
```

As far as I can tell I think I'm following the docs to the letter here, but I can't get a results box to pop, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

These are the versions of the technologies at play that I am using.

```
"rxjs": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
"bootstrap": "4.0.0",
"typescript": "~2.7.2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because you don't place `return` before your api call.

```
else {
        return this.myApiCall.employeeSearch(term)
.....
```

Comment: Good eye man! That was completely it, thanks so much for the help, sometimes you just really need an outside set of eyes on something, haha. Appreciate the help!